# How to retrieving a single column value from a datable using jquery

Tags: jquery, loops, datatable

i have a grid , in where i can select multiple rows,i need to retrieve only single column's value using jquery to send it to ajax call as data. Below is the code for retrieving all the selected row values.

```
function GetSelectedRecords() {
            var table = $('#gridview').DataTable();
            $(this).toggleClass('selected'); //for selecting multiple rows
            var AllData = [];
            $('.selected').each(function (index, value) {
               var row = table.row(value).data(); //here i get the values of selected row
               var num = table.row(value).data().__ //need something which will retrieve me its corresponding value.
                AllData.push(row);
            });
            var jsonText = JSON.stringify({ data: AllData })
            alert(jsonText);
        }
```

below is the json text data , im receiving , i need only "123"  in my variable 'num' - declared above .

```
{"data":[["123","DATA9000","DC 1","random","Reject",null,null,"JON","Card",null,"Breakdown"],["100","DATA76","DC 1","random","Reject",null,null,"abc","Card",null,"Breakdown"]]}
```

Regards,

Comment: DataTables will give you an array when calling the `.data()` method - you'll just want `table.row(value).data()[0]` in your `each` loop.

Comment: Thank you for the swift reply. It worked :)